# Escape string for conversion to URI in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, url-encoding

Is there a simple way to escape a string in SPARQL when it is to be converted to a URI?

For instance, a string with `"1 < 2"` could be converted to `"1%20%3C%202"`.

I suppose a long series of calls to the `REPLACE` function could do it, following the pattern `BIND(REPLACE(?string, '<', '%3C') AS ?escaped)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function `ENCODE_FOR_URI`:

```
ENCODE_FOR_URI("1 < 2") => "1%20%3C%202"
```

Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-encode

Comment: Extension functions for Apache Jena can be [written in Java](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_functions.html) or [written in JavaScript](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html)